# The use of 'while' and 'at the same time' in one sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-order

Can I use **'while'** and '**at the same time**' in one sentence?

For example,

> **while** cooking and listening to the radio **at the same time**

Comment: "I shall now defuse this highly explosive bomb while simultaneously, and at the same time, reciting from the works of Percy Bysshe Shelley" (Gonzo the Great, Muppet Show).

Answer (score 2):

As a part of a larger phrase, *"while cooking and listening to the radio at the same time"* is a perfectly valid sentence. For example:

> I was trying to finish all the paperwork **while cooking and listening to the radio at the same time**

As long as you have another clause before the while, the structure works well. **However** on its own, you should probably only use one of while/at the same time:

> I was cooking and listening to the radio **at the same time**
>
> I was listening to the radio **while I was cooking** (and vice versa)

Answer (score 0):

Although both have a similar meaning and use, they can still be used together like this (even if it is redundant).

Since while is a subordinating conjunction, a second clause needs to follow it. Depending on how "at the same time" is used, it can be used in a similar manner, such as

> At the same time that I was cooking, I was also listening to the radio.

or

> I was cooking at the same time that I was listening to the radio.

With both having while and "at the same time" being interchangeable.

Comment: Hmm. I'd say that "at the same time" is usually superfluous, but a person might well say that for emphasis, or to make clear that the actions were simultaneous and not alternating. Like if I said, "While I was cooking, cleaning, and playing with our baby, my wife was a t work", it would not be clear whether I meant that I performed these activities one at a time while she was at the office, or that I was trying to do all three things at once. I think they're probably assume one at a time unless I said "at the same time".

Comment: @Jay to me, those seem to happen all at the same time in that sentence. At least that she was at work while the cooking cleaning and playing occurred (the three other actions might be consecutive and not simultaneous).

Comment: *Not something that would normally be done?* That doesn't sit well with 756,000 results in Google Books for the collocation [**while at the same time**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22while+at+the+same+time%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Darn Google, always correcting me. I meant not something I normally see.

Comment: OP has only given us a phrase (not a complete sentence), so it's not easy to say whether it's "natural" for any *specific* context. But the fact that so many writers have actually used both elements *consecutively* should be enough to convince you there's something unusual about your perception here. It's completely irrelevant that both ***while*** and ***at the same time*** carry much the same meaning in such constructions - repetition / redundancy is a normal part of English. In no way, shape, or form is it "undesirable".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I guess you're right, I just saw the example as odd, but in the big picture, it's not. I'll change my answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Although what you pointed out is the use of them with "at the same time" directly after while, not in different parts of the sentence.

Comment: Well, *cooking* is a relatively unlikely verb to be used in the context of simultaneous activities (only 10 hits in Google Books), but there are hundreds of written instances of [*while **listening** at the same time*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22while+listening+at+the+same+time%22+)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, but these also only apply to a single clause and not to two joined by a coordinating conjunction.

Comment: Well, it would be difficult to come up with any particular pair of verbs for *while **X-ing** and **Y-ing** at the same time* that would yield useful results in Google Books (particularly bearing in mind that the phrase could *only* occur in a context where ***while*** refers to some *third* activity ***W-ing***). If you think it makes any difference whether there are more than two simultaneous activities being referenced, all I can say is I don't agree.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well this answer isn't very good anyways, but thanks for the constructive input. I'll leave it because of your useful comments (someone might find them helpful).

Comment: ...although I suppose I should acknowledge that the construction *could* be used of only two activities with ***while*** having a somewhat different sense: *While breathing and drinking are both common activities, it's not easy to do both at once*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers True, although it's kind of obvious by the context, but I bet some ventriloquists could pull it off.

Comment: For my money, if the two activities being referenced are things that aren't *likely* to be done at the same time (because they're in some way "incompatible" or difficult to do simultaneously), that makes it even more likely that we'd use both ***while*** and ***at the same time*** (to provide emphasis, drawing attention to the "unusual" fact of simultaneity). *He can ride a unicycle **while** juggling **at the same time***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers that's what I meant by obvious by the context that they're unlikely to be done together. I agree with you completely, that it provides the emphasis that redundancy often does in English.